# What are the End of The Line unusual effects?

Tags: team-fortress-2

What are the EOTL unusual effects that come in the crate? I only saw 2 from the tf2 site, is that all, or is there more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the item schema, there are 4 new unusual effects:

Facepunch has some images of them on its update thread (albeit not on hats; likely from a particle viewer)

**Frostbite**

[image: Frostbite unusual effect]

**Molten Mallard**

[image: Burning Duck unusual effect]

**Morning Glory**

[image: Sunrise Unusual effect]

**Death After Dusk**

[image: Sunset Unusual effect]